# Link between symfony and docker

Tags: php, docker, symfony

I'm on a symfony project and i'm using docker here's my `docker-compose.yml` :

```
version: '3.7'
services:
    db:
        image: mysql:latest
        container_name: ruakh_db
        restart: always
        volumes:
            - db-data:/var/lib/mysql
        environment:
            MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: "yes"
        networks:
            - dev

phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin:latest
    container_name: ruakh_phpmyadmin
    restart: always
    depends_on:
        - db
    ports:
        - 8080:80
    environment:
        PMA_HOST: db
    networks:
        - dev

maildev:
    image: maildev/maildev
    container_name: ruakh_mail_dev
    restart: always
    command: bin/maildev --web 80 --smtp 25 --hide-exetensions STARTTLS
    ports:
        - 8081:80
    networks:
        - dev

apache:
    build: php
    container_name: ruakh_www
    ports:
        - 8088:80
    volumes:
        - ./php/vhosts:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled
        - ./:/var/www
    restart: always
    networks:
        - dev
networks:
    dev:

volumes:
    db-data:`
```

here's **the database url** used in my symfony project :

```
DATABASE_URL=mysql://root:root@ruakh_db/ruakh
```

I'm trying to run a `php bin/console make:migration` however when i'm running I get this error :

> An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution

I'm assuming that the database url is incorrect, when I changed it to :

```
DATABASE_URL=mysql://root:root@127.0.0.1:8080/ruakh
```

This error is thrown:

> An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2006] MySQL server has gone away

How can I manage to connect my symfony project to my docker database ?

Comment: Did you try running your migration from inside or outside of the docker container ?

Comment: The container initialising the connection is expecting mysql to be running on the same container.

Comment: Did you try "docker-compose exec php bin/console make:migration" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a couple things wrong with your `DATABASE_URL`.

```
DATABASE_URL=mysql://root:root@ruakh_db/ruakh
```

- You don't set the password in your service config
- You have the wrong host name
- You don't specify the database
- You are using native authentication, which must be enabled when using MySQL 8
- (optional) your database port is not exposed

#### Password

In your `docker-compose.yml`. you do not specify the root password and instead allow for an empty password. You can set the root password using an environment variable:

```
services:
  db:
    ...
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
```

#### Database name

In order to create a default database named `ruakh` you need to provide another environment variable `MYSQL_DATABASE`.

#### Host

The next issue is the host name in your DATABASE_URL: `ruakh_db`. This is the name of the container, but not the name of the service (i.e. the host in the virtual network that docker-compose sets up). This should be `db` instead.

#### Port

You will not be able to access your mysql database from outside the docker container, because you do not expose any ports. That is not necessarily an issue, but you should be aware of it. Looking at your other database url `DATABASE_URL=mysql://root:root@127.0.0.1:8080/ruakh` this will not work, because the port 8080 is for the web interface provided by phpmyadmin. It is not the port of the actual database. Also, the port for the database is not exposed. You probably want to add:

```
services:
  db:
    ...
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
```

#### Authentication

Another issue, you will face is using the image `mysql:latest` this will use MySQL 8.0 which does not allow the authentication mechanism you want to use by default. You will have to change the command executed when running the container or downgrade to MySQL 5.7. If you want to keep MySQL 8, you should add this:

```
services:
  db:
    ...
    command:
      - 'mysqld'
      - '--character-set-server=utf8mb4'
      - '--collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci'
      - '--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password'
```

#### Summary

This is roughly what your `db` service should look like to work with your `DATABASE_URL`:

```
    db:
        image: mysql:latest
        ports:
            - '3306:3306'
        environment:
            MYSQL_DATABASE: ruakh
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'root'
        command:
            - 'mysqld'
            - '--character-set-server=utf8mb4'
            - '--collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci'
            - '--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password'
```